# How to use `vuelidate` i18n with `@nuxtjs/i18n`?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vuelidate, nuxt-i18n

I'm not sure how to follow the [docs](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/advanced_usage.html#i18n-support) in the context of Nuxt (v3 or bridge). Not sure where `i18n` would come from outside of a component.

See also:

- [github issue](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/1164)
- [StackOverflow question for `vue-i18n` usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75405042/2771889)

Answer (score 0):

In Bridge and composition API i18n comes from `useNuxtApp`:

```js
const { $i18n } = useNuxtApp()
```

But this only works if all components use composition API. If not, i18n can be passed as a workaround:

`helpers/i18n-validators.ts`

```js
import * as validators from '@vuelidate/validators'
import { NuxtI18nInstance } from '@nuxtjs/i18n'

export const createRequired = (i18n: NuxtI18nInstance) => {
  const { createI18nMessage } = validators
  // It works™
  // @ts-ignore
  const withI18nMessage = createI18nMessage({ t: i18n.t.bind(i18n) })

  return withI18nMessage(validators.required)
}
```

`Component.vue`

```js
import { createRequired } from '@/helpers/i18n-validators'
const required = createRequired($i18n)
```

Manually add translations (even english ones), e.g. `validations.required`.